# Why php mail has delay when sending message with images

Tags: html, php

I was building a email functionality for my website and I am using PHP mail function. The issue I am having is that when I try to email a client with a image inside a message it takes forever(20-45 minutes) to get to them and when I just include text it gets to them right away. Is there solution to this. Thanks for any help.

```
<?php

$email = $_COOKIE["email"];
$link = $_COOKIE["coupon"];
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Your ads';

$message = ' Hello This is Testing Email 3.0 Text & Image <a href="$link">Your Coupon Link</a> 
             <img src="$link" width="300" height="300"/>   ';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Ads <ads@advertising.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: If you put this code live, then spammers may find out that they can set an "email" cookie on their machine and then use your server as a spam relay. Until your ISP boots your website off their network, of course! Moral of the story - only send emails to addresses read from your own databases (and, of course, only to people who you can prove have signed up with you).

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you mail is a top tier Spam grade for almost all anti spamming mailing protection.

They will most likely put your mail in a slow queue because of that, delaying the message because it was considered an annoyance.

Your From header contains 'ads' and 'advertising' (even if I guess that advertising.com isn't your domain.
You also have little to no text, the word test in it and a big link button named "coupon".

You should try to make your email more personal.

This is the most likely problem.

Second one would be the file transfer.
If you're transferring from China to New-York with a 56kb/s connection, the file transfer will take long enough for your recipient to die from old age.

For your second problem, replace

```
$message = ' Hello This is Testing Email 3.0 Text & Image <a href="$link">Your Coupon Link</a> 
             <img src="$link" width="300" height="300"/>   ';
```

by

```
$message = ' Hello This is Testing Email 3.0 Text & Image <a href="' . $link . '">Your Coupon Link</a> 
             <img src="' . $link . '" width="300" height="300"/>   ';
```

Comment: Hm...this makes sense, to me anyway. However let's not leave it out of the equation that we know nothing of the image's size.

Comment: edward, if you continue reading my post, I'll explain the biggest "spam note worthy" point of his email.

Comment: @Jay, the biggest problem with the code is that the target email and link are obtained from an unauthenticated user. So yes, "top tier spam grade" indeed - it's essentially a simple spam relay.